# JProgressBar.setMaximum(int) sometimes doesn't seems to work

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I have a JProgressBar that I need to set a new `minimum`, `maximum` and `progress` value each time a task of a queue is done, using the code below:

```
this.progressBar.setMinimum(minimum);
this.progressBar.setMaximum(maximum);
this.progressBar.setValue(progress);
```

But, I noticed that sometimes, the `setMaximum(int)` method doesn't seems to work, because the progress bar still working with the old maximum value.

Then I wrote some test code and ran it:

```
progressBar.setMaximum(10);
System.out.println(progressBar.getMaximum());
```

Sometimes it prints `10` as expected, and sometimes prints the old value: anything different from 10.

I spent hours on Google and javadocs, tried to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on JProgressBar's parent, and nothing. I also tried to call `Thread.sleep(10)` to wait AWT threads to run another tasks and didn't work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Provided some more code:

```
/* Applet that construct the view and init a Thread. */
public class FastApplet extends Applet {
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private JPanel panel;
    private Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                    initThreads();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        panel.add(progressBar);
    }

    private void initThreads() {        
        runnable = new MyRunnable(progressBar);     
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }
}

/* Runnable that update progress and call setMaximum(int) on JProgressBar */
public class MyRunnable {
    private int progress;
    private final JProgressBar progressBar;

    MyRunnable(JProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do the tasks and update the progressBar using progressBar.setValue(progress)
        // when done, reset the progress bar with the a new maximum:
        defineNewProgressBar(0, 0, newMaximum);
    }

    public void defineNewProgressBar(int progress, int minimum, int maximum) {
        this.progress = progress;

        Component component = progressBar.getParent();
        JPanel panel = (JPanel) component;

        this.progressBar.setMinimum(minimum);
        this.progressBar.setMaximum(maximum);
        this.progressBar.setValue(progress);

        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the method on the EDT?

Comment: show some more code. Keep in mind swing uses a special threading system, did you put it all in one thread? This leads to unexpected behavior as per documentation!

Comment: Nope, I'm calling the method in another Thread. Actually, I have `4` threads running apart of the EDT.

Comment: @Vogel612, I'm going providing some more code.

Comment: You can access the GUI (i.e. calling the methods) on the EDT only.

Comment: I think you are calling setMaximum() method from the thread where the task is going on. You should call it from EDT using SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Comment: Provided more code and also trying the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote in your comments that you call `setMaximum()` not from the EDT. You should call it from the EDT like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        progressBar.setMaximum(10);
    }
});
```

If you use Java8, you can do this with using a lambda expression:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->progressBar.setMaximum(10));
```

Comment: Maybe because he doesn't use Java8.

Comment: Do I have to call both `progressBar.setValue(progress);` and `progressBar.setMaximum(10);` from EDT?

Comment: You have to call all GUI related code in the EDT including `setValue()`.

Comment: Ok then. I've changed my code so all GUI related code is in EDT (on Runnable called by SwingUtilities.invokelater) and the problem is gone. Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SafeProgressBarUpdaterThread](http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/software/javadoc/com/pixelmed/display/SafeProgressBarUpdaterThread.html) :

```
    progressBarUpdater = new SafeProgressBarUpdaterThread(progressBar);
     //...
    progressBarUpdater.setMaximum(maximum);
    progressBarUpdater.setValue(value);
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(progressBarUpdater);
```

Comment: Good to know about this class, I'll use that in the next project. Thank you very much for the tip. Upvoted.